# BusyBox - how to restrict access to subset of commands?

Tags: alpine-linux, busybox

## Context

I got app that is deployed on docker.
It's image is based on Alpine.

## Challenge

I created non root user just to run `java -jar JarName` command.

App is using selenium so I can't restrict access to all commands.

Most important for me is not allow him to unzip jar file.

## Question

How to do this?